# How can I test a form with FileField in Django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-testing

I have this form:

```
# forms.py

class BookForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ['book_title', 'language', 'author', 'release_year', 'genre', 'ages', 'cover']
```

**Type of fields:**
Where `book_title` and `author` are `CharField`, `language` and `genre` are too `CharField` but for them I have choice option, `release_year` and `ages` are `IntegerField`, and the last `cover` are `FileField`.

**Choice Options:**

```
# models.py
ENGLISH = 'english'
LANGUAGE_CHOICES = (
    (ENGLISH, 'English'),
)

ADVENTURE = 'adventure'
GENRE_CHOICES = (
    (ADVENTURE, 'Adventure'),
)
```

**Now:** I want to test this form, but I don't know how can test `cover`, here is my form test.

```
# test_forms.py
from .. import forms
from django.core.files import File


class TestBookForm:
    def test_form(self):
        form = forms.BookForm(data={})
        assert form.is_valid() is False, 'Should be invalid if no data is given'

        img = File(open('background'))

        data = {'book_title': 'Lord Of The Rings',
                'language': 'english',
                'author': 'J. R. R. Tolkien',
                'release_year': 1957,
                'genre': 'adventure',
                'ages': 16,
                'cover': img}

        form = forms.BookForm(data=data)

        assert form.is_valid() is True
```

**I tried:**
    from django.core.files.uploadedfile import SimpleUploadedFile

```
img = open('background')
uploaded = SimpleUploadedFile(img.name, img.read())
{'cover': uploaded}
```

**This is my error:**

```
E       assert False is True
E        +  where False = <bound method BaseForm.is_valid of <BookForm bound=True, valid=False, fields=(book_title;language;author;release_year;genre;ages;cover)>>()
E        +    where <bound method BaseForm.is_valid of <BookForm bound=True, valid=False, fields=(book_title;language;author;release_year;genre;ages;cover)>> = <BookForm bound=True, valid=False, fields=(book_title;language;author;release_year;genre;ages;cover)>
.is_valid
```

**NOTE:** I use `Python 3.5`, `Django 1.9.4` and I start test using `py.test`.

**UPDATE:** If i try `open('background.jpg')` don't work. **Error:** `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'background.jpg'` **I fix this**

**UPDATE 2:**

I try to use `mock`

```
from django.core.files import File
import mock

file_mock = mock.MagicMock(spec=File, name='FileMock')
file_mock.name = 'test1.jpg'

{'cover': file_mock}
```

I try to use `InMemoryUploadedFile`

```
from io import BytesIO
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import InMemoryUploadedFile
from PIL import Image

im = Image.new(mode='RGB', size=(200, 200))  # create a new image using PIL
im_io = BytesIO()  # a StringIO object for saving image
im.save(im_io, 'JPEG')  # save the image to im_io
im_io.seek(0)  # seek to the beginning

image = InMemoryUploadedFile(
    im_io, None, 'random-name.jpg', 'image/jpeg', None, None
)

{'cover': image}
```

I fix the path to my image.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**I find the problem** This is my code:

```
#test_forms.py
from .. import forms
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import SimpleUploadedFile
import os

TEST_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
TEST_DATA_DIR = os.path.join(TEST_DIR, 'data')


class TestBookForm:
    def test_form(self):
        form = forms.BookForm(data={})
        assert form.is_valid() is False, 'Should be invalid if no data is given'

        test_image_path = os.path.join(TEST_DATA_DIR, 'background.jpg')

        data = {'book_title': 'Lord Of The Rings',
                'language': 'english',
                'author': 'J. R. R. Tolkien',
                'release_year': 1957,
                'genre': 'adventure',
                'ages': 16}

        with open(test_image_path, 'rb') as f:
            form = forms.BookForm(data=data, files={'cover': SimpleUploadedFile('cover', f.read())})
            assert form.is_valid(), 'Invalid form, errors: {}'.format(form.errors)
```

More info in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/api/#binding-uploaded-files)

Comment: Thank you! I had to add the file ending here:

SimpleUploadedFile('cover.png', f.read())})

Answer (score 0):

Either you create a file in your repository, so it is there physically, or you mock your test for your file.

Try [THIS](https://joeray.me/mocking-files-and-file-storage-for-testing-django-models.html)

---

**EDIT**

Try to pass full path

```
import os
from django.conf import settings
file_path = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, your_folder, background.jpg)
```

Comment: I tried to make a fake file but don't work, after I put a file in my package and i tried to put on `cover` field. This is my last option? My file must be `jpg`, `png` or `jpeg`

Comment: Where did you place your background.jpg file ? It has to be in place, where you run test from. So let's say if you run your test from main folder, the background.jpg has to be there

Comment: My `test_forms` are in `tests` package, and my `background.jpg` are in same package. But when I try `open('background.jpg')` it don't works... but `open('background')` works...

Comment: As I said, place the file inside your main folder. Or, pass a full path to a file. I`ve added code to my answer. Check it mate

Comment: That was works for file but I tried a new assert: `assert 'cover' not in form.errors` and the __ERROR__ is `E       assert 'cover' not in {'cover': ['This field is required.']}`